# Python: Extract all possible mutually exclusive pairs?

Tags: python, graph, combinations, combinatorics

I have an assignment problem where I have N participants and need to find all possible 2-person assignments where every participant is assigned to exactly one pair.

When I use `list(combinations(range(100), 2))` I get a "flat" list of about 4000 items, each a pair in the form of (i,j).

This is not what I'm looking for; there needs to be three levels of this array:
`[ [(1,2), (3,4),...], [(1,3), (2,4),...], ...  ]`

What's the best way to accomplish this effect in Python?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the result would contain N! lists, which is too much even for moderately large N. Are you sure your task is to produce all those list and not to calculate something else from those lists? Or is your N some small number like 5?

Comment: Hmm, good question! So to add some more context, I need to assign participants to groups such that the summed Euclidean distances across all pair assignments is minimized. I used Xpress and found a solution in 2 seconds. Exhaustively iterating through all possibilities is my notional idea to validate results. However, I don't think that I need to use N=100, I could use N=10 to validate that the MILP solution find the global optima on a toy problem of reduced size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a recursive generator function:

```
def parings(L):
    if len(L)<=2:           # only 2 elements, single pair
        yield [tuple(L)]
        return
    for j in range(1,len(L)):                # first element paired with every other
        for rest in parings(L[1:j]+L[j+1:]): # with all pairings of remaining elements
            yield [(L[0],L[j])] + rest


for p in parings([1,2,3,4,5,6]): print(p)
                   
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 6)]
[(1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 5)]
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6)]
[(1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 6)]
[(1, 3), (2, 6), (4, 5)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5)]
[(1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 6)]
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)]
[(1, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

With N=10 you still get a reasonable number of patterns:

```
L = list(range(10))
print(sum(1 for _ in parings(L))) # 945
```

but it gets unmanageable real quick:

```
L = list(range(18))
print(sum(1 for _ in parings(L))) # 34,459,425
```

To decide on the size of your toy problem, you could adapt the recursive function to compute the number of results like this:

```
def pairingCount(N):
    if N<=2: return 1
    return (N-1) * pairingCount(N-2)

print(pairingCount(18)) # 34,459,425
```

Mathematically, the count can be expressed using factorials:

```
                n!
count =  ----------------
         (n/2)! * 2^(n/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_assignments(N):
    assignments = []
    size = N//2 
    elems = list(range(N))
    C = list(combinations(elems, size))
    for c in C:
        A = set(c)
        B = list(set(elems).difference(A))
        P = list(permutations(B))
        for p in P:
            edges = [(c[i], p[i]) for i in range(size)]
            assignments.append(edges)
        
    return assignments
```